# Proper lme4 equation with fixed and random effects for group differences

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I  have a dataset comprised of whole fish concentrations (LAB_RESULT.x), filet fish concentrations (LAB_RESULT.y), and species name (COMMON_NAME.x). I am attempting to run a linear mixed effects model to determine the relationship between filet to whole fish concentrations by species, and if there is a difference among species in this model. This is a step to eventually see if a single linear model works for all species or if there is significant differences between species.

[image]

I put together the model:

```r
lmer(LAB_RESULT.x ~ COMMON_NAME.x + (1|LAB_RESULT.y), 
     data = SHFvFilet)
```

and get an output, but am struggling to determine if this is the proper equation for this question, as well as how to properly determine what the output is representing. From my understanding this is showing that for individual species whole fish concentration, species such as Largemouth Bass are significantly different than the overall model, and should not be included in an overall model, while those that are not significant could be included in an overall model. I am also using the lmerTest package with Satterthwaite's method being used to produce p values.
Output:
[image]

[image: Image added to answer dandrews comment]

Comment: Welcome to CV. It looks like you specify LAB_RESULT.y as the random intercept. Why? This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks! LAB_RESULT.y was placed as the random intercept from my interpretation of page 4 of the lmer vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf). It created the output syntax (where COMMON_NAME.x was shown as the individual fixed effects), where as others that I tried (such as lmer(LAB_RESULT.x ~ (1|COMMON_NAME.x) + LAB_RESULT.y, 
data = SHFvFilet) ) did not.

Comment: In the example on page 4, observations are nested within subjects (i.e., there are several observations for each subject). In your case, the nesting factor should be COMMON_NAME.y. Just because you get some output when you specify LAB_RESULT.y as the random intercept does not justify this modeling decision.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is a different model. Have you considered an interaction between species and filet concentration, say in linear regression, before moving to mixed effects modeling?

Comment: It seems to me that these are nested measurements since they are two measures of the same variable in two parts of the fish. Which would suggest that the syntax from pg. 4 would work `lmer(LAB_RESULT.x ~ (LAB_RESULT.y + (COMMON_NAME.x|LAB_RESULT.y), data = SHFvFilet)). Would it not?

Comment: I don't think so, but @levane07 should clarify further. The formula does not make sense for me in any case.

Comment: @levane07 May I suggest some initial data exploration by plotting. This will help to understand if the nature of the relationship is linear or curvilinear and requiring data transformation or fitting on a link scale which will help with specifying the model formula. The first step here seems to be to step back and start simply, and build complexity into your modeling as is necessary to avoid breaking modeling assumptions. It seems maybe there is some confusion over what each specification actually does e.g including random slopes and/or intercepts.

Comment: There is a linear relationship between filet and whole, without a data transformation step, that was found using linear regression. From that, I was looking to determine if a single model works for all, or if individual species may be different from than an all encompassing model. To answer dandrews, both the equation shown on page 4 of the lmer vignette and the equation dandrews constructed result in an error and a result, but I dont believe it to be the one I am looking for as it covers all species together, not individually (updated in the original post). Let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: If you have convergence issues, your data doesn't support the random effects structure. After trying different optimizers (see `help("convergence")`) the only solution is usually to simplify the random effects structure. However, if you need individual coefficients for the species, you should just model it as a fixed effect. Of course, you might run into issues of overfitting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the advice that you should plot your data.

However: I'm sorry, but the mixed model you propose doesn't make any sense. This is obvious, because a continuous variable cannot be the grouping variable of a random effect.

> I have a dataset comprised of whole fish concentrations (LAB_RESULT.x), filet fish concentrations (LAB_RESULT.y), and species name (COMMON_NAME.x). I am attempting to run a linear mixed effects model to determine the relationship between filet to whole fish concentrations by species, and if there is a difference among species in this model. This is a step to eventually see if a single linear model works for all species or if there is significant differences between species.

OK, so if there is no impact of species, your model would look like this:

```
fit0 <- lm(LAB_RESULT.y ~ LAB_RESULT.x, data = DF)
```

I believe you can just use a fixed-effects model including the species:

```
fit1 <- lm(LAB_RESULT.y ~ LAB_RESULT.x * COMMON_NAME.x, data = DF)
```

You can then check if the species effect is significant using the `anova` function:

```
anova(fit1, fit0)
```

Obviously, you will need to do the usual checks regarding model assumptions.

If you have many species, a mixed-effects model might be an alternative. With a random intercept:

```
fit2 <- lmer(LAB_RESULT.y ~ LAB_RESULT.x + (1 | COMMON_NAME.x), data = DF)
```

or with a random intercept, slope and their covariance:

```
fit3 <- lmer(LAB_RESULT.y ~ LAB_RESULT.x + (LAB_RESULT.x | COMMON_NAME.x), data = DF)
```

Again, you can check significance of the species effect using `anova`:

```
anova(fit3, fit2, fit0) #test random slope and test random intercept
anova(fit3, fit0) #test the entire species effect
```

Again, assumptions need to be checked.

Comment: Hi Roland thank you so much, this makes a lot(!!!) more sense than what I was attempting, and was extremely thorough and easy to follow. After following this and confirming all assumptions this seems to me what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: One more quick question @Roland , for fit 3 the COMMON_NAME.x is being shown as a random effect, instead of a fixed effect. to show as a fixed effect would that just be: fit3 <- lmer(LAB_RESULT.y ~ LAB_RESULT.x * COMMON_NAME.x, data = DF), then any further random effects could be added with "(1|random effect)" ?

Comment: I don’t think you understand what a random effect is. I encourage you to read this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-87458-6